# Make iTunes song options stick on other devices?

Tags: iphone, itunes, ipad, data-synchronization, audio

When I set certain options for a song, such as a Volume Adjustment or Start Time or Stop time, it would be nice if those options were kept when the song is played on another device, such as an iPad or iPhone.

For example, if I cut off the first several seconds of a song (say, to get rid of a spoken introduction), iTunes will do that and start the song proper, but the same tune played on the iPad will start at the beginning (including the spoke intro).

Is there some way to get iTunes to modify the actual file rather than some internal database (or whatever)?

Comment: How do you sync your music between your devices? I've also got a song which I've set a stop time on in iTunes, and it's being obeyed on my iPhone and iPad as well. It was originally synced via iTunes, not wirelessly.

Comment: Originally, straight iTunes sync, wired.  Lately, occasionally wireless, but still iTunes.

Answer (score 1):

While I'm not sure why the options aren't being kept between your device, there is no way to make iTunes edit the file itself. Nearly everything Apple makes revolves around the idea of revisions. iTunes, while not using revisions, only edits it's database to mark the in and out points of tracks.

To correct syncing, I can only suggest removing the song from iOS and adding it back (it doesn't rewrite data for tracks already on the device).

The get around this, you can always edit the file yourself in something like [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net), if you wanted to go the permanent route.